# How to override a component's function in Polymer 2?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I'm using [app-localstorage-document](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-storage/elements/app-localstorage-document) to store data in the browser. The documentation says to override `zeroValue` method to define the default value to use when there's no data stored. But I don't know how to override the component's method in Polymer. Here's what I tried but I don't think it's correct because the function is not being invoked.

```
<app-localstorage-document key="CatValue" data="{{cat}}"></app-localstorage-document>

class MyApp extends Polymer.Element{
   static get is(){return 'my-app';}
   static get properties(){
     return{
       cat:{
         type: String,
         value: ""
       }
     };
   }

   zeroValue(){
     this.set('cat',"a cat");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
<app-localstorage-document key="CatValue" data="{{cat}}"></app-localstorage-document>

class MyApp extends Polymer.Element{
   static get is(){return 'my-app';}
   static get properties(){
     return{
       cat:{
         type: String,
         value: function() {
              return this.zeroValue;
         }
       }
     };
   }

   //Override the default method
   get zeroValue(){
     return 'a cat';
   }
}
```

If you do not want to override zeroValue(), it will store the value of the key CatValue as undefined.

Comment: It works, but unlike `iron-localstorage-load-empty`, the `zeroValue()` gets invoked every time. I know that's because we're trying to receive the value from method. But can we make it happen something like `iron-localstorage-load-empty` so that the method doesn't get invoked every time?

Comment: Also `this.set('key',"some value");` doesn't updates the value in local storage. Any idea why it doesn't?

Comment: If you add an argument to get zeroValue(), what will the value say? I.e. get zeroValue(value);

Comment: @RickardElimää it says, Uncaught SyntaxError: Getter must not have any formal parameters.

Comment: @RickardElimää as you can see in the documentation at https://www.webcomponents.org/element/polymerelements/app-storage/elements/app-localstorage-document  : zeroValue is getter to define the default value to use when there's no data stored. Try changing the name of the function other than zeroValue will help you.

Comment: @AmanshuKataria after you set the value you need to notify. Use this.notifyPath('key');. Also, you might need to put notify:true for that key. For more information go to: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data

Comment: Here is the plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/g7YHiJ?p=preview . Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Ofisora I'm having issue with the objects for `this.set()`. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: But if you use `<input type="text" value="{{cat}}"></input>`, `cat` will not keep the last value when you reload the page, as it would with `<iron-localstorage name="o_login" value="{{cat}}" on-iron-localstorage-load-empty="_initStorage"></iron-localstorage>`

Comment: @AmanshuKataria I think this is different. Please ask a new question.